# Ubuntu like user switching in Windows7?

Tags: windows, user-accounts

One of my favorite features on ubuntu is how there is a drop down of all the users on my machine.  Then I can select one of them and I am immediately switched to another user.

Then on windows7, I must open the windows menu, click an arrow, click 'Switch User', then I am brought to the login screen and then finally I click the other user I want to use.

Not the end of the world, but it certainly gets tiresome if I switch accounts a lot.

I do not have passwords on any of my user accounts.  Is there a way to make win7 work like ubuntu in this regard?  Even a script would be great.

Thanks for reading!

Comment: Quick tip - on ubuntu multiple users are logged on to different virtual terminals, so you can quickly switch with just keys.  In X (GUI) ctrl-alt-F7 should be your first login, and higher F keys may have different user's sessions.(although if memory serves me correctly some distros leave 7 or 8 for console logging so one of them may be blank/text - use alf-f1 to switch from text-consoles).

Comment: Some distros (actually, most of them in my experience, but I don't know for sure) actually put their text log on vterm1, and X sessions starting at vterm7. In general, though, the X sessions have to be somewhere, and there's only 9 options to try, so just look around for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I must open the windows menu, click an arrow, click 'Switch User',

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

> Even a script would be great.

The `tscon` command can be used to connect to another Terminal Services session (`qwinsta` for a list). Unfortunately, if the target session's account has no password, `tscon` will not be allowed to connect to the session (due to the "Only allow blank passwords for console logins" restriction). You can get around this by running `tscon` under the *`LocalSystem`* account with `psexec -si tscon <id>`. It's not very convenient, though.

Task Manager has a "Users" tab with a "Connect" option, but the same password restrictions apply.

There used to be a few programs that offerered Alt+Tab-like user switching... One of them was part of Microsoft *PowerToys for Windows XP*, later discontinued; the other I can't find right now, and I think it was limited to XP too.